# Are Biome Locations Patterned and Predictable?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a special way to detect in which direction a certain biome is or are the biomes randomly configured?

Comment: There is probably a mod that adds biome info to the F3 info menu

Comment: @Robotnik There's biome information in F3 about the biome you're in already. Adding info about biomes you're not in—I have a hard time imagining how the code could work, or how it would decide what to show you.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - I must've misread the question, I thought it was asking for the best way to tell where the edge of a biome was. I also didn't know there was biome info in the F3 menu already (It's not something I worry about often)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biomes are randomly distributed.

Given the exact seed though, you can always reproduce the same world and biomes layout. Third-part tools can exploit this fact to show you the biomes for any place in a world, whether it actually exists in your save yet or not. [AMIDST](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/626786-v21-amidst-strongholds-village-biome-etc-finder/) is one tool that can do this for you.